# ¿Como puedo fijar un determinado tamaño de letra para la consola donde se va a ejecutar mi programa hecho en C++?

Tags: c++, consola, codeblocks

Quisiera saber si hay un modo de fijar el tamaño de letra de la consola con codigo C++ antes de ejecutar mi programa.
Me explico, por ejemplo si yo quiero cambiar el tamaño de letra de la consola de manera manual, lo que hacemos es presionar click derecho en la parte superior y dandole click en propiedades. (Como se muestra en la siguiente imagen)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego cambiamos el tamaño de la letra de la consola manualmente introduciendo el valor del tamaño al que queremos cambiar como se muestra en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues bien yo quisiera hacer esto mismo pero desde codigo, para fijar un determinado tamaño de letra a mi conveniencia, para que al ejecutarse mi programa, sin importar que tamaño de letra halla tenido antes por defecto, se cambie al que yo indique(y si es posible que ya no se pueda cambiar del ya establecido por mi) .

Comment: Puedes hacerte una idea de lo que te servirá mirando [la documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions). [Aquí tienes una respuesta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35382432/13419694).

Comment: Gracias!, viendo la documentacón hallé la función de aqui https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setcurrentconsolefontex  y creo que me serviría ,se llama SetCurrentConsoleFontEx , pero no estoy seguro aún y por otro lado aun nose como se implementaria ya que implica varios argumentos que aun no acabo de entender. :'v

Comment: Edita la pregunta con lo que hayas intentado. Así la pregunta será mejor recibida.